# AWS Glue unable to access a view

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, pyspark, view, amazon-athena

I have a view registered in Glue / Athena, call it my-db.vm_view. I'm able to query it via Athena and everything generally seems to be in order.

I'm trying to use this table in a Glue job with glue context, but I am getting the following fairly opaque error message:

py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o95.getCatalogSource.
: java.lang.Error: No classification or connection in my-db.vm_view

On the other hand, I'm trying to use this table in a Glue job with spark.sql and show me the error Error Category: QUERY_ERROR; AnalysisException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not create a Path from an empty string

Has anyone experience with this error and what might be causing it?

A way to get a view from AWS